# jquery- Enter text into textbox/textarea as subsequent button is pressed on the keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Thanks in advance!

I want to perform an event on an input box/text area using jQuery.

Scenario:

Note: Input box/text area is not visible on the page. [There is only 1 input box/textarea on the page].

When any alphabetic/numeric key is pressed the input box becomes visible on the page.
And the corresponding keyValue (eg. if "a" key is pressed keyValue="a") is entered into the input box/text area

Comment: You are likely going to want to make use of the `.keypress()` function - http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 1):

You could use an approach like below, first hide the text area with visibility: hidden, as event won't work on display: none elements, then apply a keypress event handler on the textarea and compare each key code on each input 65 is for 'a', when 'a' has been inputed make the textarea visible, using visibility: visible.

```
// focus the text area so the user would input inside it
$('textarea').focus();
$('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
   if(e.keycode === 65) {
      $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
   } else {
     // delete any unwanted text
     $(this).val('');
   }
});
```

css:

```
/* hide the textarea through visibility hidden */
textarea { visibility: hidden; }
```

EDIT: you can find a full list of keyCodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)